# Not binding an event to one of li items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this navbar code

```
<ul class="left">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Support</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">First Sub</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I have this event handler in my js file

```
$('ul.left li:not(:last-child), ul.dropdown li:not(:last-child)').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var ul = this.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(this);
});
```

The problem: The Add in the ul.left isn't bound to the click event handler (and it mustn't be according to my reqs). But the Add in the ul.dropdown is bound to the click event handler although I have specified that the last child of li should not be binded. So, it deletes the parent li item, that is 'Support'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have a class called `dropdown` you have a class called `has-dropdown` so `ul.dropdown li:not(:last-child)` selector won't work at all. On top of that your first selector `ul.left li:not(:last-child)` will cover all of the li elements in your inner list so you'll also need to change you first selector to be something like: `ul.left > li:not(:last-child)` in order to only select li elements that are direct descendants of the first list.

So if your only changing your js change your selector to :

```
'ul.left > li:not(:last-child), ul.has-dropdown > li:not(:last-child)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the "direct descendant" operator `>` to specify only `<li>` elements directly under your specific `<ul>` elements.

The problem here is that this part of your selector: `ul.left li`

matches like so:

```
0:<li><a href="#">First</a></li>
1:<li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Support</a>
    <ul>
2:    <li><a href="#">First Sub</a></li>
3:    <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
4:<li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
```

so the `:not(:last-child)` is only killing off that last li (`<li><a href="#">Add</a></li>`)

---

by using `ul.left>li`, you'll only get matches:

```
0:<li><a href="#">First</a></li>
1:<li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Support</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">First Sub</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
2:<li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
```

---

The full selector you're looking for is:

`'ul.left > li:not(:last-child), ul.dropdown > li:not(:last-child)'`

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would probably just add a class to the `add` button.

HTML

```
<ul class="left">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Support</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">First Sub</a></li>
      <li class="add"><a href="#">Add</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="add"><a href="#">Add</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('ul.left li:not(.add)').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var ul = this.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(this);
});
```